# How to drop a list of rows in a multi index frame using Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following frame

Column1---Column2--- Column3----Column4 ----- Column5
Entry1----------xxx--------- yyyy ---------    3151   -----------  6542
-------------------ggg----------    ffff----------     4647-------------587----
-------------------hhh ----------    llll---------     46847----------    321321
Entry2 --------- xxx --------    yyyy--------     215--------------      1231
        -------------------ggg  ---------   ffff--------     12321------------5487
------------------        hhh   ----------  llll  ---------   1321 -----------5854
Entry3---------  xxx ----------    yyyy   -------  4564 ------------    123
-----------------        ggg   -----------  ffff  -----------   6654 -----------    135
-----------------        xxx ------------    llll -----------    46542 ---------   1348

For every entry, I would like to keep rows where Column2 is xxx
The result shoud look like
Column1 Column2 Column3   Column4   Column5
Entry1  -----xxx --------    yyyy-----      3151 -----     6542
Entry2 ------ xxx ------    yyyy -----     215-------       1231
Entry3  ------xxx -------    yyyy ----     4564------      123

I tried several combinations but can't find the correct one.
Any ideas?

Comment: For `Entry3`, you have `xxx` twice. You don't need the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to keep your MultiIndex you could use

```
df.loc[(slice(None), 'xxx'), :]
```

or

```
df.query('Column2 ==  "xxx"')
```